# Regex in powershell for getting assembly version number

Tags: regex, powershell, assemblyversions

I am trying to create a script that will find and return the assembly version from the solution. It covers some of the test scenarios, but I cannot find the correct regex that will check is the version in correct format (1.0.0.0 is ok, but 1.0.o.0) and that contains 4 digits? Here is my code.

```
function Get-Version-From-SolutionInfo-File($path="$pwd\SolutionInfo.cs"){
$RegularExpression = [regex] 'AssemblyVersion\(\"(.*)\"\)'
$fileContent = Get-Content -Path $path
foreach($content in $fileContent)
{
    $match = [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($content, $RegularExpression)
    if($match.Success) {
        $match.groups[1].value
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try `$RegularExpression = [regex] 'AssemblyVersion\("(\d(?:\.\d){3})"\)'`

Comment: please add a few lines of your `$fileContent` collections to see what works with that specific data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change your *greedy* capture group, `(.*)`, to a *non-greedy* one, `(.*?)`, so that only the very next `"` matches.

  - The alternative is to use `([^"]*)`
- To verify if a string contains a valid (2-to-4 component) version number, simply cast it to `[version]` ([`System.Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Version)).

Applied to your function, with optimized extraction of the capture group via the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375):

```sh
function Get-VersionFromSolutionInfoFile ($path="$pwd\SolutionInfo.cs") {
  try {
    [version] $ver = 
      (Get-Content -Raw $path) -replace '(?s).*\bAssemblyVersion\("(.*?)"\).*', '$1'
  } catch {
    throw
  }
  return $ver
}
```